# Can't use microphone with speech recognition

Tags: python, pi-4, speech-recognition

I'm developing a voice assistant program with python and speech recognition. On windows everything is ok and it works. But on linux i got errors.I'm running raspbian buster on pi 4.

here is the code :

```
 for i, microphone_name in enumerate(mic_list): 
        if microphone_name == self.getMic():
            device_id = i 
with sr.Microphone(device_index = device_id, sample_rate = sample_rate,  
                                chunk_size = chunk_size) as source:
```

and the errors in eclipse console right after running the program :

```
    Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 924
    Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 924
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.front.0:CARD=0'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM front
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround21
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround21
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.surround40.0:CARD=0'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround40
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround41
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround50
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround51
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.surround71.0:CARD=0'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround71
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM iec958
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM spdif
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM spdif
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
    Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 934
    Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 934
    Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 934
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'defaults.bluealsa.device'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5036:(snd_config_expand) Args evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM bluealsa
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'defaults.bluealsa.device'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5036:(snd_config_expand) Args evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM bluealsa
    ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
    ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
    ALSA lib pcm_a52.c:823:(_snd_pcm_a52_open) a52 is only for playback
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=6,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM iec958:{AES0 0x6 AES1 0x82 AES2 0x0 AES3 0x2  CARD 0}
    ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
    ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
    Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 924
    Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 924
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.front.0:CARD=0'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM front
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround21
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround21
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.surround40.0:CARD=0'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround40
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround41
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround50
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround51
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.surround71.0:CARD=0'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround71
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM iec958
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM spdif
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM spdif
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
    Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 934
    Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 934
    Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 934
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'defaults.bluealsa.device'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5036:(snd_config_expand) Args evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM bluealsa
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'defaults.bluealsa.device'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5036:(snd_config_expand) Args evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM bluealsa
    ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
    ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
    ALSA lib pcm_a52.c:823:(_snd_pcm_a52_open) a52 is only for playback
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=6,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM iec958:{AES0 0x6 AES1 0x82 AES2 0x0 AES3 0x2  CARD 0}
    ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
    ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
    Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 924
    Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 924
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.front.0:CARD=0'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM front
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.rear
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.center_lfe
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.side
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround21
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround21
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.surround40.0:CARD=0'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround40
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround41
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround50
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.surround51.0:CARD=0'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround51
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.surround71.0:CARD=0'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM surround71
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM iec958
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM spdif
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM spdif
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.hdmi
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.modem
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM cards.pcm.phoneline
    Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 934
    Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 934
    Expression 'alsa_snd_pcm_hw_params_set_period_size_near( pcm, hwParams, &alsaPeriodFrames, &dir )' failed in 'src/hostapi/alsa/pa_linux_alsa.c', line: 934
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'defaults.bluealsa.device'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5036:(snd_config_expand) Args evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM bluealsa
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'defaults.bluealsa.device'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5036:(snd_config_expand) Args evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM bluealsa
    ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
    ALSA lib pcm_oss.c:377:(_snd_pcm_oss_open) Unknown field port
    ALSA lib pcm_a52.c:823:(_snd_pcm_a52_open) a52 is only for playback
    ALSA lib confmisc.c:1281:(snd_func_refer) Unable to find definition 'cards.bcm2835_alsa.pcm.iec958.0:CARD=0,AES0=6,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
    ALSA lib conf.c:4568:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib conf.c:5047:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file or directory
    ALSA lib pcm.c:2565:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM iec958:{AES0 0x6 AES1 0x82 AES2 0x0 AES3 0x2  CARD 0}
    ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
    ALSA lib pcm_usb_stream.c:486:(_snd_pcm_usb_stream_open) Invalid type for card
```

Comment: What kind of microphone is connected to the Pi 4?

Comment: @Botspot samsong usb microphone.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same situation as you, I find out the warnings are created by the pyaudio but don't impact on it working normally.

You can delete the warned sound cards in the file `/usr/share/alsa/alsa.conf` or you can use `os.close(sys.stderr.fileno())` to close the sys warning reference (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36956083/how-can-the-terminal-output-of-executables-run-by-python-functions-be-silenced-i).

I hope the answer can figure out your problem.